# Transform an object with properties of same length list to a list of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, lodash, map-function

I have an object of this format. Each key is a list of the same length:

```
myobj = {
    'key1' : [1, 2, 3],
    'key2' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'key3' : [true, false, true],
    ...,
    'keyN' : ['length', 'of', 'three'],
}
```

I need to transform this object to a list of "smaller" objects, so the object with position `i` in the final list will have the respective values of each initial list (with index `i`). So this would be the result of the above object:

```
[
    {
        'key1' : 1,
        'key2' : 'a',
        'key3' : true,
        ...,
        'keyN' : 'length'
    },
    {
        'key1' : 2,
        'key2' : 'b',
        'key3' : false,
        ...,
        'keyN' : 'of'
    },
    {
        'key1' : 3,
        'key2' : 'c',
        'key3' : true,
        ...,
        'keyN' : 'three'
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a fairly straightforward thing to write.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are the things you have tried till now. You can try something like following.

```js
var a = {'key1' : [1, 2, 3],
    'key2' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'key3' : [true, false, true]}

var result = []

Object.keys(a).map(key => {
  a[key].forEach((item, index) =>  result[index] ? result[index][key] = item :      result[index] = {[key]: item})
  }
 )
 
 console.log(result)
```